# How to select the first name of each Title?

Tags: mysql, join, select, min, pgadmin

I am using Pgadmin (mysql). I have to print one name for date (the first year) So my code give me this:

```
 "El padrino";1972
 "El padrino";1972
 "El padrino";1972
 "El resplandor";1980
 "El resplandor";1981
 "Buenos muchachos";1990
 "Buenos muchachos";1990
 "Forrest Gump";1994
 "Forrest Gump";1994
 "Tiempos violentos";1994
 "Tiempos violentos";1995
 "Los 7 pecados capitales";1995
```

And I need to take the first name of each movie with the oldest year. Like this:

```
 "El padrino";1972
 "El resplandor";1980
 "Buenos muchachos";1990
 "Forrest Gump";1994
 "Tiempos violentos";1994
 "Los 7 pecados capitales";1995
```

I am trying with the following code:

```
SELECT min(titulo), MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR from f.fecha))
FROM pelicula p, f_estreno_pais f 
WHERE p.id_pelicula = f.id_pelicula
GROUP BY p.id_pelicula, f.fecha
ORDER BY f.fecha;
```

But also, I do not have to drop the table! I have to make a select for only the first time the Title it is showed.

Comment: In questions like this where the code is not in english it is particularly helpful to have sample data,

Comment: Oh true, my bad! For next time I will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just want to remove the movie year from the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT min(p.titulo), MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR from f.fecha)) min_fecha
FROM pelicula p
INNER JOIN f_estreno_pais f ON p.id_pelicula = f.id_pelicula
GROUP BY p.id_pelicula
ORDER BY min_fecha;
```

This gives you one row per movie, with the minimum movie year.

Side notes:

- always use standard, explicit joins (with the `ON` keyword) rather than implicit joins (with commas in the `FROM` clause); this old syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code
- in a multi-table query, always prefix all columns with the table they belong to - this makes the query unambiguous and easier to follow

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me... I was trying this for many days. I appreciate your hepl